# Group by or Distinct - But several fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

How can I use a `Distinct` or `Group by` statement on 1 field with a `SELECT` of All or at least several ones?

Example: Using SQL SERVER!

```
SELECT id_product, 
  description_fr, 
  DiffMAtrice, 
  id_mark, 
  id_type, 
  NbDiffMatrice, 
  nom_fr, 
  nouveaute
From C_Product_Tempo
```

And I want `Distinct` or `Group By nom_fr`

JUST GOT THE ANSWER:
select id_product, description_fr, DiffMAtrice, id_mark, id_type, NbDiffMatrice, nom_fr, nouveaute
from   (
       SELECT rn = row_number() over (partition by [nom_fr] order by id_mark)
              , id_product, description_fr, DiffMAtrice, id_mark, id_type, NbDiffMatrice, nom_fr, nouveaute
       From C_Product_Tempo
       ) d
where  rn = 1

And this works prfectly!

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of data and what you are trying to achieve in the end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want the first row per `nom_fr`. If so, you can simply use a subquery to get the lowest `id_product` per `nom_fr`, and just get the corresponding rows;

```
SELECT * FROM C_Product_Tempo WHERE id_product IN (
  SELECT MIN(id_product) FROM C_Product_Tempo GROUP BY nom_fr
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e454/2).

Comment: Thanks Joachim Isaksson. You understood correctly, and it is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what to do with the other fields. For example, for numeric fields, do you want a sum?  Average?  Max?  Min?  For non-numeric fields to you want the values from a particular record if there are more than one with the same `nom_fr`?

Some SQL Systems allow you to get a "random" record when you do a `GROUP BY`, but SQL Server will not - you must define the proper aggregation for columns that are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is used to group in conjunction with an aggregate function (see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), so it's no use grouping without counting, summing up etc. `DISTINCT` eleminates duplicates but how that matches with the other columns you want to extract, I can't imagine, because some rows will be removed from the result.